# Questions concerning Object Oriented Programming theory in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am learning some theory behind OOP C++ programming. Our professor provided us with some sample questions so that we could make a revision before an exam. 
Could you please take a look and check if I am correct? I would be really thankful for any advices.

a) Public methods have an access to private class members **(true)**

b) Friend function has an access to the private class members of a class **(true)**

c) Private class members are accessible in derived classes **(false)**

d) Private class members are not inherited so they are not accessible in derived classes. **(true)**

e) Public class members are not accessible for Friend classes. **(false)**

f) Friend class has only an access to private and public class members of class which it is friends with. **(false)**

g) Protected class members are accessible in derived classes **(false)**

Comment: Why is this c) Protected attributes are accessible in derived classes (false) false?

Comment: While [attributes are a thing in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), I'm pretty sure this is not what your professor is referring to. Thus, the terminology here makes very little sense.

Comment: What i meant referring to attributes was class members: methods and fields. Attributes is how we call it in polish. It was lost in translation i guess. Sorry.

Comment: Private class members are definitely inherited, they are simply not accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> c) Protected attributes are accessible in derived classes (false)

That's wrong. `protected` members are very much accessible in derived classes. That's the whole *point* of `protected`.

*Attributes* are an entirely different thing, though. Get your terminology straight.

Comment: Meanwhile, the OP has edited the question and changed two things: 1. He changed the letter from c) to g) . 2. He removed all reference to "attributes". I submitted an edit to adapt the answer to the edited question, but this edit was rejected.